# Retrieve AssemblyCompanyName from Class Library

Tags: c#, .net

I would like to get the AssemblyCompany attribute from a WinForm project inside of my C# class library.  In WinForms, I can get to this information by using:

```
Application.CompanyName;
```

However, I can't seem to find a way to get at that same information using a class library. Any help you could provide would be great!

Comment: The AboutBox accesses and displays most of the Assembly Information (although not the Build Date). I just launch the AboutBox form, Minimised, to which I added some code to pop the required fields into a Common Class, and Close the Form.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

To get the assembly in which your current code (the class library code) actually resides, and read its company attribute:

```
Assembly currentAssem = typeof(CurrentClass).Assembly;
object[] attribs = currentAssem.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AssemblyCompanyAttribute), true);
if(attribs.Length > 0)
{
    string company = ((AssemblyCompanyAttribute)attribs[0]).Company
}
```

Comment: I don't know if this is because I'm in .NET 2.0, but I had to add "true" to the end of call for GetCustomAttributes.  Other than that, worked like a champ!  Thanks for your help!

Comment: I found it very useful! If you are using a new .NET version you can use typeof(CurrentClass).Assembly.GetCustomAttribute<AssemblyCompanyAttribute>().Company

Answer (score 8):

You could use the [`FileVersionInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.fileversioninfo) class to get `CompanyName` and much more.

```vbnet
Dim info = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(GetType(AboutPage).Assembly.Location)
Dim companyName = info.CompanyName
Dim copyright = info.LegalCopyright
Dim fileVersion = info.FileVersion
```

Comment: Why would you use fileinfo to get information about the same assembly that's already in scope?

Comment: @lorddev The only way I see to get a FileVersionInfo object is by calling the static/shared GetVersionInfo function that takes a string path.  Other options?

Answer (score 4):

```
Assembly assembly = typeof(CurrentClass).GetAssembly();
AssemblyCompanyAttribute companyAttribute = AssemblyCompanyAttribute.GetCustomAttribute(assembly, typeof(AssemblyCompanyAttribute)) as AssemblyCompanyAttribute;
if (companyAttribute != null)
{
    string companyName = companyAttribute.Company;
    // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The dotnet 5 version:

```
typeof(CurrentClass).GetCustomAttribute<AssemblyCompanyAttribute>().Company
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also get it using LINQ :

```
public static string GetAssemblyCompany<T>(){
    string company = (from Attribute a in (typeof(T).Assembly.GetCustomAttributes())
        where a is AssemblyCompanyAttribute
        select ((AssemblyCompanyAttribute)a).Company).FirstOrDefault();

    return company;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a great way to get what you are looking for in a single line:

```
string company = ((AssemblyCompanyAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), typeof(AssemblyCompanyAttribute), false)).Company;
```