# Get company name and copyright information of assembly

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly

I am using `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName()` to get application/assembly name and its version but I do not see any variable for company name and copyright. How do I get that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1626801/1324019

Comment: I see [lots of useful stuff](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+get+assembly+company+name+copyright&oq=c%23+get+assembly+company+name+copyright&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58.5195j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8) with a Google search. Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You can use [FileVersionInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.fileversioninfo.aspx) like this:

```
var versionInfo = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);

var companyName = versionInfo.CompanyName;
```

Comment: This answer might not work with "Single File" published assemblies. (see for help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file )

Comment: Maybe, the answer were thought mainly for full (old) .NET Framework.

Comment: Yeah, just letting others who may have come here looking for an answer (like me) find what they need faster. It took me a couple hours to figure out why this was working in debug, but not after publishing.

Answer (score 17):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1626825/593627) for the company name:

```
Assembly currentAssem = typeof(CurrentClass).Assembly;
object[] attribs = currentAssem.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AssemblyCompanyAttribute), true);
if(attribs.Length > 0)
{
    string company = ((AssemblyCompanyAttribute)attribs[0]).Company;
}
```

Code is similar for the copyright, use `AssemblyCopyrightAttribute` instead of `AssemblyCompanyAttribute`.

Answer (score 5):

Those are attributes that you have to enumerate on the Assembly object using reflection.

```
var attributes = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AssemblyCompanyAttribute), false);

var attribute = null;
if (attributes.Length > 0)
{
    attribute = attributes[0] as AssemblyCompanyAttribute;
}
```