# How to get and set DLL file details, using C#

Tags: c#, dll

I want to get and set the detail properties of a `.dll`:

[image]

E.g., I want to get the Copyright and File Version information, and I want to set the Copyright and File Version information.

Comment: You can check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19384193/get-company-name-and-copyright-information-of-assembly

Comment: 【 enter image description here】 link  is  dll picture

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get company name and copyright information of assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19384193/get-company-name-and-copyright-information-of-assembly) This is to get this information. To set it you should update `AssemblyInfo.cs` file in your project

Comment: i want to update .dll files detial property.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the GetVersionInfo of the FileVersionInfo class

[GetVersionInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.fileversioninfo.getversioninfo?view=netframework-4.6.2)