# log4net file path using project Assembly info

Tags: c#, .net, log4net

I have the following in `log4net.config` that defines my logger:

```
  <!-- Setup Rolling Log File to log all information -->
  <appender name="DebugFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender" >
    <file value="${ProgramData}\\My Company\\My Product\\log\\Debug" />
    <appendToFile value="true"/>
    <rollingStyle value="Date"/>
    <datePattern value="_yyyy-MM.\tx\t"/>
    <staticLogFileName value="false"/>
    <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock"/>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date %-5level - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
```

Is there a way to use the project's `Assembly.cs` info that would allow me to build the log path like:

```
<file value="${ProgramData}\\${AssemblyCompany}\\${AssemblyProduct}\\log\\Debug" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using log4net's [GlobalContext](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.GlobalContext.html) along with a [Pattern Layout](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Layout.PatternLayout.html) in the file config.

So before configuring you set the values (there's an example of getting them from the AssemblyInfo [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1626801/retrieve-assemblycompanyname-from-class-library))

```
// Properties must be set before configuration

log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["Company"] = "Company Name";
log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["Product"] = "Product Name";

log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(…);
```

Then in the config (note the file type must be `PatternString`):

```
 <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" 
       value="${ProgramData}\%property{Company}\%property{Product}\Log\Debug\log.log" />
```

This would evaluate to `C:\ProgramData\Company Name\Product Name\Log\Debug\log.log`